# Can someone tell me on how to print Fibonacci series, but the user will choose the start and the endpoint

Tags: java, recursion, user-input, fibonacci

Like the user chooses 55 as the starting point and 987 as the end and the series will be like
The series is: 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues do you face?

Answer (score 0):

You could just calculate the Fibonacci sequence starting from 1 to the endpoint and once you reach the start point, you can start adding the numbers to an empty array. This weeds out all the ones that aren't necessary and accomplishes the task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay this is actually the question, Write a Java Program that will display a the series of Finabonacci Series but the starting and ending point of the series will be determined by the user. Take note the error handling especially in taking the initial and ending value for the said series.

Comment: But I've tried using arraylist, which is good btw but the sequence has limitations when using arraylist, I used long instead to int but long can't sustain much bigger numbers.  And then I decided to use for loops like to print to the 92nd term of the Fibonacci, but I cant figure how to print the middle numbers, just start and the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closed form expression of the n-th Fibonacci number which is given by (sorry, because of lack of reputation I can not insert a math formula, only a link to that formula at google chart)

[https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left[\left(\frac{1%2b\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}\right]](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=F_n=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt5%7D%5Cleft%5B%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%2b%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bn%7D-%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cright%5D)

Also there are some details with examples in R which could be useful
https://fabiandablander.com/r/Fibonacci.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use in dynamic programming approach
save the first 2 numbers in the series in this example num1 = 55, num2 = 89
and sum = num1 + num2
you can get num2 by running fib on dynamic programming approach till it will get to the start value limit(starting point)

```
public int fibWithLimit(int start1,int start2, int end) {
int num1 = start1, num2= start2, sum;
while(sum <= end) {
    sum = num1+ num2;
    num1= num2
    num2 = sum;
  }
 return sum;
}
```